# Looking for a app or software which could help me search for free to use images

Tags: web-apps, mobile

Looking for a app or software which could help me search for free to use images.

Either download them or save them to google drive.

Using google images maybe ?

Edit:

Highlighting the must have requirement "ability to download" selected images in a single go.

With Google Images and Pixabay we can search, but we can't select and download. That's the functionality I am after, sorry if I wasn't clear enough.

Comment: Google image search, CC license?

Comment: https://ccsearch.creativecommons.org/

Comment: I don’t understand. With Pixabay you absolutely can select and download. Otherwise, what would the point of the site be?

Answer (score 1):

Not an app, but a website. [Pixabay](https://pixabay.com/) claims to have more than 1 million free images, illustrations, vector images and videos. All searchable and filterable by image type, size, orientation, color and category. From the website:

> Pixabay is a vibrant community of creatives, sharing copyright free
>   images and videos. All contents are released under the Pixabay
>   License, which makes them safe to use without asking for permission or
>   giving credit to the artist - even for commercial purposes.

In addition, using Google, you can search for images and using the "Tools" button, can filter by license type.

[image]